# Linq Get items higher then lastname

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, lambda, filtering

Greetings

I'm trying to find a way using Linq-to-SQL to get the first 15 records which have a higher last name then "Jan".

When I use this in SQL I get every member which lastname starts with any letters higher then "Jan" on alphabetical order.

However using `query.Where(m=>m.LastName > "Jan")` does not work sadly.

Anyone know how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Would "Jansen" be a valid last name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
query.Where(m => m.LastName.CompareTo("Jan") > 0)
```

That's how you'd write it in normal C#, after all.

It's not clear whether this is LINQ to Objects or some other provider. If it's LINQ to Objects, you should consider using an explicit StringComparer. For example:

```
query.Where(m => StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Compare(m.LastName, "Jan") > 0)
```

this makes it clear what kind of comparison you want. If you're using something like LINQ to SQL, that may not work - I would imagine you'll get whatever sort of comparison the provider can handle, basically.

Comment: The first solution works. Sadly I aint got enough rep to up this!

Comment: Just a small sidenote,
With this it gets everything above "Jan" but it skips "Jan" .. is there a way to include him ?

Comment: @Theun: Just change `> 0` to `>= 0`.

Comment: True, just figured that out after I posted the edit but forgot to remove it :P

Answer (score 0):

```
query.Where(m => m.Substring(0, 3).CompareTo("Jan") > 0);
```