# Finding location in list,

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, list, datagrid

In [Linq Get items higher then lastname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723219/linq-get-items-higher-then-lastname) I asked how to get people higher then a certain name.

However we use a datagrid with paging and when showing only people higher then lastname "Jan", there's no way to get back to people starting with AA.

So I was searching for a way to find out on what location the person would have been if following the normal order of selection?

hope this makes sense :)

[edit]
The query type is of EntityQuery.
[/edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to solve this problem using the example given at
[Getting to certain member using datapager and datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737233/getting-to-certain-member-using-datapager-and-datagrid)

Answer (score 1):

So you want the index of first person record that matches your condition?

```
var index = query.TakeWhile(person => person.LastName.CompareTo(name) < 0).Count();
```

This counts the number of elements that match the condition and the returned value is the index of the first element that does not match with the condition.

Just note that you must negate the condition that you used with Where() as in this case TakeWhile() is used to get the items that you don't want.

Comment: TakeWhile seems to be not available on a EntityQuery. Am I missing a namespace?  If not hopefully you can supply a alternative method.

Comment: I have never used EntityQuery and it seems to have pretty limited set of query operations. Can you convert it to list with ToList() and then use the TakeWhile() method?

Comment: No, converting it to a list would mean I have to first get all records from the database.
Using a entityQuery I can limit the amount of records taken from the database and thus limit the amount of data transfered.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a problem with ToList(). You still can limit the number of records that are taken from the database, but it works well only when the condition operates in the beginning of the dataset as the TakeWhile() solution requires all preceding records.

Comment: I have a database with over 4000 records in it. If your way is to work, and the person would be "Zen" instead of "Jan", I would first have to get all people before "Zen" in my application to find the location of him and then get the people after "Zen" aswell.
This is something we wish to avoid because we want to limit the data over the netwerk to as few as possible.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant by saying that the method works well only when the condition operates in the beginning of the dataset. In the worst case all records has to fetched and I do understand that it is considered to be a problem. Alas, I haven't discovered any other solution.